# How to show a different field's value in an Ext grid grouping header?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs4, grouping

I have an Ext.grid.Panel that I'd like grouped by a field, but to display a different field in the grouping header. For example, if my model has `status_id` and `status_name` fields, I'd like to group by `status_id`, but show the `status_name` in the group header.

I've played around with the `groupHeaderTpl` option but no luck so far. How can this be done?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can debug the grouperHeaderTpl values by doing

```
groupHeaderTpl:'{[console.log(values)]}'
```

That way you can observe all the posible values and select the correct path to obtain the value you are looking for. In this case what you need to do is

```
groupHeaderTpl: '{[values.rows[0].data.status_name]}'
```

Here you can find the whole example

```
/* Sample Data */
var data = [ 
         { "status_id": 1, "status_name": "Pending"}, 
         { "status_id": 2, "status_name": "Ready"}, 
         { "status_id": 3, "status_name": "Processing"}, 
         { "status_id": 4, "status_name": "Unavailable"},
         { "status_id": 5, "status_name": "Ready"}, 
       ];

/* Model */
Ext.define("StatusModel", {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: ['status_id', 'status_name']
});

/* Store */
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
storeId:'statusStore',
model: "StatusModel",
groupField: 'status_id',
data: data,
proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    reader: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
});

/* Grouping Feature */
var groupingFeature = Ext.create('Ext.grid.feature.Grouping',{
   groupHeaderTpl: '{[values.rows[0].data.status_name]}'
});

/* Grid Panel */
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
title: 'Status',
store: Ext.getStore('statusStore'),
columns: [
    { text: 'Id',     dataIndex: 'status_id' },
    { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'status_name', flex: 1}
],
features: [groupingFeature],
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexrom7/shZLf/1/

Comment: Nice solution though I thought I shouldn't access in that way to data.